# How to make a copy of my moodle production site

Tags: moodle

I am trying to make a copy of my moodle production site so that I can test an upgrade before upgrading the production site. I created a directory and copied the `moodledata`, `moodle code` and `mysql database` into the new directory but now I am stuck. Can someone please tell me the next steps to take? I want to have a live copy (that it should open on a web browser) of the moodle site.

Comment: Did you read Moodle migration documentation? https://docs.moodle.org/32/en/Moodle_migration

Comment: Yes i did but it talks about copying from one server to another. In my case, i just want to have another moodle instance on the same server. I need guidance to this please, i have no prior knowledge of installation, upgrade and so on, from command line interface. Thanks

Comment: Can you please mention your web service.
If you are using AWS, then you can just create an image and spin up another EC2 instance with that same production image.